# Flutter in_app_purchase pastPurchases is 0 on iOS

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I've followed this guide:

https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-inapp-purchases/

However pastPurchases.length is 0 on iOS, despite buying an auto renewing subscription with the sandbox user. On android everything works just fine.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with the code.

In order to make it work I had to create a sandbox user.

- Then I had to log out from my current logged in AppID on the phone.
- Then I had to "Edit Scheme" in Xcode from Release to Debug.
- Then I ran "flutter run" in terminal.
- Then I purchased my NonConsumable subscription, and in the dialog I had to enter the sandbox user email and pwd.